# Aurora MySQL Cluster - how to identify Read Replica

Tags: python, boto3, amazon-aurora

We have a bunch of Aurora MySQL Clusters, need to identify which instances are Masters and which are Read Replicas, using boto3.  Cluster endpoints have "-ro-" in their replica names.  Is this the only way?
  Apologies if this has been answered already.

Answer (score 1):

Finally found it ... Need to use "describe_db_cluster_endpoints" method.

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client('rds', 'my-region')
my_cluster = client.describe_db_cluster_endpoints(DBClusterIdentifier='my-aurora-cluster')
print my_cluster
```

and look for 'EndpointType', there will be 'WRITER' or 'READER'